# useState conflicts with async operations in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, react-hooks

In a React functional component with the `useState` hook I don't know how to run multiple async operations without having conflict on the final result.

If the initial state is an object and every async operation performs a change on a given key, it's possible to use the spread operator in order to set a new state. Example:

```react
const [oldState, setNewState] = React.useState({ /* something */ });
const asyncOperation = async () => {
   await somethingAsync();
   setNewState({
      ...oldState,
      key: 'newValue',
   });
};
```

The problem emerges when more of those operations run in the same time: the `oldState` used during `setNewState` may be changed by the end of another async function, but some updates of the state may be lost when the last async operation performs his `setNewState` since the reference to `oldState` can point to an old version of the variable.

[Here's a demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/sweet-meninsky-d2ugx?fontsize=14): try to click every button in a row and, in the end, some of them will (probably) result still loading.

How can I avoid this problem without leaving react hooks?

Comment: *"Here's a demo:"* Please put the runnable example **here, on-site** using Stack Snippets (the `[<>]` toolbar button). Stack Snippets support React, including JSX; [here's how to do one](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/338537/). People shouldn't have to go off-site to help you, and making it on-site makes it easy for them to give you a corrected version.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

For [async operations](https://reactjs.org/docs/state-and-lifecycle.html#state-updates-may-be-asynchronous), you need to make use of the previous state using the updater function.

```
setNewState((previousState) => ({
  ...previousState,
  key: 'newValue',
}));
```

In here, `oldState` is != `previousState`.

Comment: @ Duma - That is, your `oldState` may be out of date by the time the async function uses it. Using the callback version of `setNewState` ensures you're using the up-to-date version.